# Generating hex dump images in Android Real device

Tags: android

I'm downloading the images from server and store into External storage using ImageLoader.But in my real device the images stored into generating hex dump and the file is opened in read only mode and file name is also changed.Why not images are stored in .jpg and .png format.Here is my Screen Shot.Can someone help me for how to resolve this issue.Thanks.

[image]

FileCache class

```
    public class FileCache {

        private File cacheDir;

        public FileCache(Context context){
            //Find the dir to save cached images
            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"classnkk_images");
            else
                cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
            if(!cacheDir.exists())
                cacheDir.mkdirs();
        }

        public File getFile(String url){
            //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
            String filename= String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
            //Another possible solution (thanks to grantland)
            //String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
            File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
            return f;

        }

        public void clear(){
            File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
            if(files==null)
                return;
            for(File f:files)
                f.delete();
        }

    }

ImageUrlLoader class

    public class ImageUrlLoader {


        int fixedHeight = 230;
        MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
            FileCache fileCache;
            private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews= Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
            ExecutorService executorService;
            Handler handler=new Handler();//handler to display images in UI thread

        public ImageUrlLoader(Context context){
            fileCache=new FileCache(context);
            executorService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
            }

        final int stub_id= R.drawable.img_placeholder;
        public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
            {
            imageViews.put(imageView, url);
            Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
            if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
            {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
            }

            private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
            {
            PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
            executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
            }

            private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
            {
            File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

            //from SD cache
            Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
            if(b!=null) {
                return b;
            }

            //from web
            try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
            } catch (Throwable ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
            memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
            }
            }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
            try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
            stream1.close();

    //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=470;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
            }

    //Task for the queue
       private class PhotoToLoad
       {
            public String url;
            public ImageView imageView;
            public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i)
            {
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
            }
        }

        class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            }catch(Throwable th){
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

        boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
            if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
            {photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     }

            else
            {
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
                Log.e(" In Image Loader ", " 33333333333333333333333");
            }

        }
    }
   public void clearCache() {
            memoryCache.clear();
            fileCache.clear();
        }}

MemoryCache class

    public class MemoryCache {

        private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";
        private Map<String, Bitmap> cache= Collections.synchronizedMap(
                new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10, 1.5f, true));//Last argument true for LRU ordering
        private long size=0;//current allocated size
        private long limit=1000000;//max memory in bytes

        public MemoryCache(){
            //use 25% of available heap size
            setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
        }

        public void setLimit(long new_limit){
            limit=new_limit;
            Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to " + limit / 1024. / 1024. + "MB");
        }

        public Bitmap get(String id){
            try{
                if(!cache.containsKey(id))
                    return null;
                //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
                return cache.get(id);
            }catch(NullPointerException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
            try{
                if(cache.containsKey(id))
                    size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
                cache.put(id, bitmap);
                size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
                checkSize();
            }catch(Throwable th){
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void checkSize() {
            Log.i(TAG, "cache size=" + size + " length=" + cache.size());
            if(size>limit){
                Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();//least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated
                while(iter.hasNext()){
                    Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
                    size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                    iter.remove();
                    if(size<=limit)
                        break;
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size " + cache.size());
            }
        }

        public void clear() {
            try{
                //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
                cache.clear();
                size=0;
            }catch(NullPointerException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if(bitmap==null)
                return 0;
            return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
        }
    }

Util class

    public class Utils {
        public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
        {
            final int buffer_size=1024;
            try
            {byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
                for(;;)
                {
                  int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
                  if(count==-1)
                      break;
                  os.write(bytes, 0, count);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }

And here is my code line in Adapter class
String str_DownLoadUrl = namespace + "/DownloadFile/FilePathMobile/ATTACHMENT/FileName/"+value;
                                imageUrl_Loader.DisplayImage(str_DownLoadUrl , imageView);
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply .

Comment: @Nigam Patro : I have just post my code .

Comment: That is a picture of a hex editor showing an image file. Your file is ok. Take the gallery app or another imageviewer to display it.

Comment: And do one thing, you are not giving any file extension to the image

Comment: but the problemm is when i want to give that images names compare with SQlite image column names at that it gives issues.